# When using pointers (new int[size]), does size need to be established before the code?

Tags: c++

If I have a code like this:

```
int* array = new int[n];
```

Can the value of `n` be directly resized?

If I'd have an example, would this be permissible or would `ArrSize` need to be defined to a set value that cannot change before I start the example?

```
int* newArr = new int[ArrSize];
int j = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < Size; i++){
    if(arr[i] > 0){
        newArr[j] = arr[i];
        j++;
        ArrSize++;
    }
}
return newArr;
```

Comment: incrementing `ArrSize` does not increase the size of the array pointed to by `newArr`. Is it that what you are asking?

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 incrementing _after_ the array has been allocating. My understanding is, op tries to find out whether one can allocate VLAs on heap in C++.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I'm asking if I can use this like vectors I guess. If I do this example, and I defined ArrSize initially to be 0- if it'd increment by 4 (bc of ArrSize++), would the newArr store 4 variables in an array on the heap? If not, I guess the only option would be vectors?

Comment: "Allocating VLAs on the heap" is an oxymoron.

Answer (score 2):

> Can the value of n be directly resized?

You can do anything you like to `n`. However, such things will not *retroactively* change any code that has previously executed. That never happens in imperative languages.

If you create an array with `n` elements, that array's element count will be the value of `n` at the time the array was created. Indeed, *every* use of `n` will be based on the value of `n` at the time.

You should be using a `vector<int>` instead of an explicit array for what you're trying to do

Answer (score 1):

> Can the value of n be directly resized?

You can change the value of the variable `n` (assuming it is non-const).

But no, the array does not refer to the provided size indirectly. Changing a variable (if any) that may have been used in initialising the size of the array has no effect on the size of the array. In fact, there is no way to change the size of an array at all in C++.

To achieve something similar, you would have to use a "resizable array" data structure which works by creating dynamic objects onto a dynamic buffer of memory, which can be "resized" by copying (moving) the contained elements into a new buffer of another size, destroying the old elements and then deallocating the old buffer. There is no need to implement it yourself though, since the C++ standard library has a generic template which implements such data structure. It's called `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

> Can the value of n be directly resized?

No